# Example direct sum of injective modules is not injective

Tags: homological-algebra, injective-module

We knew that a direct product of injective modules is injective but a infinite direct sum need not be. I searched many article about this problem, and all most given a counter-example is: the **Bass-Papp** Theorem. So, is there a easy example about that, meaning, over $Z, Q...$

Thanks for regarding my question!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103402/the-direct-sum-of-injective-modules-need-not-be-injective

Comment: A ring is (left) noetherian if and only if every direct sum of injective (left) modules is injective.

Comment: In particular over nice rings (Z,Q,...) there won't be a counterexample.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: thanks, that's all I need

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan, egreg: thanks, I knew that before